# How to install this software with Git and NPM on a Mac

Tags: git, typescript, npm, command-line, server

I want to install some software from GitHub onto my Mac. The problem is, the instructions the developer has provided are extremely minimal. Either that or I'm just too much of a noob at command line and package management.

This is the GitHub page: https://github.com/sehugg/8bitworkshop

<sup>(Backstory: It's an IDE for authoring 8-bit games for NES, Atari, etc. that runs [in a browser](https://8bitworkshop.com/). But I want to manage multiple projects in different folders, and that won't be possible unless I can get it running locally on my machine.)</sup>

The instructions provided are as follows...

### Install

To build the 8bitworkshop IDE:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
npm i
npm run build
```

### Usage

Start a web server on http://localhost:8000/ while TypeScript compiles in the background:

```
make tsweb
```

### Run Tests

```
npm test
```

That concludes the instructions. Now for the things I seek clarification about...

### Part 1 - Git

I have Git installed. I know this because when I type `git --version` I see `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`
But [apparently that version is old](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-git-macos/) and it probably came with Command Line Tools. So should I (A)uninstall this version and install the latest one? (B)Attempt to update this version to the latest one? (C)Leave it alone because I don't need the latest version? (And what's the best way to do whichever of those options is advised?)

What do the submodule commands do? ([Looks complicated.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)) Do I even need to know, or should I just type them?

### Part 2 - NPM

I don't have NPM installed yet, and I know very little about it. All web searches for NPM also turn up Node.js. While I don't think I need Node.js(?), if installing Node.js also gives me NPM (as [this video](https://youtu.be/rF1ZHmqvm8I?t=119) shows), I will do it.

After NPM is installed I'm guessing I should `cd` to the unzipped `8bitworkshop-master` folder and then type `npm i` and `npm run build`.

### Part 3 - TypeScript & Setting up a web server

This is the first time I've heard of TypeScript. Google tells me it's "a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript". I guess I should do `make tsweb` within the `8bitworkshop-master` folder?

There are apparently different ways to set up a web server on macOS.

One is with the [SimpleHTTPServer](https://lifehacker.com/start-a-simple-web-server-from-any-directory-on-your-ma-496425450).

Another is by editing `httpd.conf`, as is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78wFR5Rp_Mw).

And then there's [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html#download-apple), which I've used before but I'm not sure would work in this particular case.

If anyone can advise on the best way to set up a web server to run this IDE, I will be grateful.

### Part 4 - Test

So I will type `npm test` and something will happen? What will I be testing? Not exactly sure. I suppose there will be some kind of feedback to tell me that I either succeeded or failed.

If you've read this far, thank you. The reason I ask about these steps is that I want to gain as much knowledge as possible before attempting instead of just blundering through. There have been times when I've ended up having multiple versions of programming languages installed in different locations, or reached almost the end of a setup process only to have some error occur leaving a bunch of files copied to who-knows-where. And fixing those kinds of issues is even harder than the installation to begin with. So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had downloaded the project as a .zip file instead of cloning the repository with Git.

### Prerequisites

Python 3, Command Line Tools, and Git (included with Command Line Tools) should be installed.

[**pyenv**](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/python-virtual-environments-mac) is the best way to install Python 3 on a Mac that shipped with Python 2.

### Step 1 - Git

Decide where to clone the repository to, and `cd` into that directory using Terminal.

Next, type:
`git clone https://github.com/sehugg/8bitworkshop.git`

Type: `cd 8bitworkshop` (You can Tab to auto-complete)
This puts you in the newly created subfolder.

Type:
`git submodule init`

Once that’s done, type:
`git submodule update`

### Step 2 - NPM

Install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
(NPM comes with it)
The LTS version is probably best.

Verify that NPM is installed by typing in Terminal:
`npm -v`
It should list the installed version.

Type:
`npm i`

If a message appears about vulnerabilities, type `npm audit fix`

Any "npm WARN" messages can be ignored.

You may see "2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated". Ignore this.

Type:
`npm run build`

### Step 3 - Web Server

type:
`make tsweb`

After that, in a browser go to http://localhost:8000/

It really is that easy. I was overthinking this process.

### Step 4 - Test

Finally, type:
`npm test`